# R - R2HTML Inserting Title before existing content

Tags: html, r, title

Currently I have an existing HTML file, I am trying to add a Title to the HTML file, using `HTML.title()` function of the `R2HTML` package. Unfortunately the title is getting added to the bottom of the content, how do I ensure that the title appears on Top?

Similar is the case for a graph `HTMLInsertGraph()`this is adding the graph below the existing content.

The other approach could be creating new HTML using `R2HTML` and then putting the existing the HTML into it then the sequencing should be ok, but I do not know how to achieve this.

Either ways I want the Title and Graph above my existing HTML content file

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create a New HTML, write the title and then add the HTML bit